# Trouble limiting the duration of an Oscillator in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, audio, buffer

I'm having a bit of trouble limiting the duration of this oscillator to around 10 seconds using audiolib.js. When I was using the dsp.js library, I limited the duration using the bufferSize, but I have absolutely no idea how to do it using the audiolib.js library... Any help would be great! While I'm at it, would anyone be able to tell me the max and min Frequency and amplitude as well?

```
$(document).ready(function () {

    //var context = new webkitAudioContext();
    var playing;
    var dev = audioLib.AudioDevice(audioCallback, 2);
    var osc = audioLib.Oscillator(dev.sampleRate, 440);
    //var bfo = audioLib.Oscillator(dev.sampleRate, 1.0);
    //osc.addAutomation('frequency', bfo, 0.5, 'modulation');
    osc.waveShape = 'pulse';

    function audioCallback(buffer, channelCount) {
        if (playing) {
            //bfo.generateBuffer(buffer.length / channelCount);
            osc.append(buffer, channelCount);
            //remove the audiocallback function
        }
    }

    $('#playButton').click(function () {
        playing = true;
    });

});
```

Cheers!

Comment: What do you mean by "max and min Frequency and amplitude"? Of the oscillator?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sample rate is number of samplers per second, so you can calculate the number of samples to play by multiplying the sample rate times 10 seconds:

```
var maxSamples = dev.sampleRate * 10;
```

You could then use it like this:

```
$(document).ready(function () {

    var playing;
    var dev = audioLib.AudioDevice(audioCallback, 2);
    var osc = audioLib.Oscillator(dev.sampleRate, 440);
    var maxSamples = dev.SampleRate * 10;
    var totalSamples = 0;
    osc.waveShape = 'pulse';

    function audioCallback(buffer, channelCount) {
        if (playing) {
            osc.append(buffer, channelCount);
            totalSamples += buffer.length / channelCount;
            if (totalSamples >= maxSamples) {
                // remove audioCallback
                dev.kill();
            }
        }
    }

    $('#playButton').click(function () {
        playing = true;
    });

});
```

Comment: Thanks, that's great... Don't worry about the max/min frequency/amplitude. How would I remove the audioCallback?

Comment: I updated the code above to include a call to dev.kill(). According to the audiolib.js author, this is the preferred (and only) method. Unfortunately you'll need to create a new instance of AudioDevice to start the audio back up again, but this is the only way I know of to remove the audio callback.

Comment: Jon_091 - does this answer your question or are you still looking for additional information before marking the answer as accepted?

Comment: It doesn't answer my question, but it is the correct method for Firefox. dev.kill() does not work for the web audio api. Sorry, I've just realised I didn't mention that when I was describing my problem :/